# Converting video from NTSC to PAL

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a request from Polish TV to send an SD file to them with these specs:
16:9 square pixel 1920x1080, 50 interlace

What I have is 720x486 NTSC.

My recipe for SD to HD 1920 x 1080 is:

```
ffmpeg -i input_file -filter:v "colormatrix=bt601:bt709, scale=1440:1080:flags=lanczos, pad=1920:1080:240:0" -c:a copy output_file
```

Can I just insert `-target pal-`?

I was thinking of going to ProRes 422 HQ, so would this work?

```
ffmpeg -i input_file -c:v prores -profile:v 3 -filter:v "colormatrix=bt601:bt709, scale=1440:1080:flags=lanczos, pad=1920:1080:240:0" -target pal- -c:a copy output_file
```

Answer (score 2):

> Can I just insert `-target pal-`?

**No.**

`pal` is a prefix to the target file type. So it has to be used in combination with `vcd`, `svcd`, `dvd`, `dv`, `dv50`. An example is `-target pal-dv`. These are all old, legacy, SD file types.

See the `-target` option in the [`ffmpeg` documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options) for a list of options each target sets.

> I was thinking of going to ProRes 422 HQ [using `-target pal-`], so would this work?

**No.** Same reason as above. It will give you an error:

```
Unknown target:
Failed to set value 'pal-' for option 'target': Invalid argument
```

> So, is there any way to encode something from NTSC to PAL with FFMPEG? Another filter? sounds like the target has presets that are useless to me. But is there one to switch to PAL and 50i?

Use the [fps filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps) (or `-r` option) to change the frame rate.

```
ffmpeg -i input_file -filter:v "fps=25, colormatrix=bt601:bt709, scale=1440:1080:flags=lanczos:interl=1, pad=1920:1080:240:0" -c:a copy output_file
```

Comment: Yes, all of those commands ( vcd, svcd, dvd, dv, dv50) were old, SD, types, so I didn't want to use them.

Comment: So, is there any way to encode something from NTSC to PAL with FFMPEG? Another filter? sounds like the target has presets that are useless to me. But is there one to switch to PAL and 50i?  thank you very much for the feedback and answers. I have been working today on this and not found anything to work yet . . .

Comment: @EwokBBQ See updated answer.